# CSS Animation Won't Play Per Click

Tags: javascript, html, css

I built a carousel for some images. I need my 'next' and 'previous' buttons to use the CSS animation that I assigned them in my javascript function for their event listeners.The animation will only play for one click, and when the buttons are clicked again to navigate the carousel the animation doesn't play. I need the buttons to grow and shrink for every click.

Here's the CSS:

```css
.carousel-actions {
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 105%;
  top: 30%;
}
.carousel-actions button {
  padding: 30px 50px;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.329);
  font-weight: 900;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 100px;
  border: 0;
  font-size: 60px;
  color: black;
  outline: none;
}
@keyframes grow {
  0% {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
  50% {
    transform: scale(1.3);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}
```

Here's the HTML:

```html
<div class="carousel-actions">
  <button id="prev" aria-label="Previous Slide"><</button>
  <button id="next" aria-label="Next Slide">></button>
</div>
```

Here's the JS:

```js
const slides = document.querySelectorAll(".carousel-item");

const totalSlides = slides.length;

let slidePosition = 0;
console.log(totalSlides);
const next = document.getElementById("next");
const prev = document.getElementById("prev");
function hideAllSlides() {
  for (const slide of slides) {
    slide.classList.remove("carousel-item-visible") &&
      slide.classList.add("carousel-item-hidden");
  }
}

function nextSlide() {
  hideAllSlides();
  if (slidePosition === totalSlides - 1) {
    slidePosition = 0;
  } else {
    slidePosition++;
  }
  slides[slidePosition].classList.add("carousel-item-visible");
  next.style.animation = "grow 1s";
}
function prevSlide() {
  hideAllSlides();
  if (slidePosition === 0) {
    slidePosition = totalSlides - 1;
  } else {
    slidePosition--;
  }
  slides[slidePosition].classList.add("carousel-item-visible");
  prev.style.animation = "grow 1s";
}
next.addEventListener("click", nextSlide);
prev.addEventListener("click", prevSlide);
```

Comment: The code you've posted here has not retained any formatting and contains several syntax errors - can you please review it and ensure that this is *exactly* how you intended to post it? It's very difficult to parse as-is.

Comment: @esqew Do you mean that I should indent it? I'm not aware of any syntax errors in my code. I didn't include all the code from the project because I didn't think it was necessary.

Comment: You definitely should indent it, at least here for others' readability. As far as syntax goes, for starters: the line `slide.classList.remove('carousel-item-visible') && slide.classList.add('carousel-` isn't complete and will in fact throw an error regarding syntax. Finally, I'm not suggesting at all you include the entire project's code in your question - not only would that not be possible, but not helpful either. Ensure the code you've provided conforms to the [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) guidelines.

Comment: @esqew ```slide.classList.remove('carousel-item-visible') && slide.classList.add('carousel-``` continues onto the next line only on stackoverflow. It's only cut off because of the code formatting on stackoverflow. There is no syntax error here as the full line of code is clearly ```slide.classList.remove('carousel-item-visible') && slide.classList.add('carousel-item-hidden');```

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not seeing the same. For me, there is an explicit linebreak in that spot. Normally, code blocks don't wrap to the next line and instead introduce a horizontal scrollbar when a line is too wide for the width of the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is seen because once the system has played the animation it thinks 'well, I've played it'. Setting it to the same again does not make it play again.

To get round this you can unset the animation when it has finished.

In your code add an event listener for the animationend event.

Here's a simplified example:

```js
const div = document.querySelector('div');
div.addEventListener('click', function() { div.style.animationName='grow';});
div.addEventListener('animationend', function() { div.style.animationName='';});
```

```css
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: blue;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
}
@keyframes grow {
  0% {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
  50% {
    transform: scale(1.3);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
```

```html
<div></div>
```