# Trying to trigger CSS keyframes animation every time button is clicked

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-animations

As the title says, I am trying to make it so that the CSS keyframes animation is triggered each time the 'generate horoscope' button is clicked. It works on the first click of course, but subsequent clicks don't reactivate it. I thought that by removing the animate class from the element before adding it in the function would achieve this but it doesn't and I can't work out why.

Please see code below, any help would be greatly apreciated:

```js
window.onload = function() {
    /* array of 'signs' for first part of message output */
    const signsArray = ['Sun', 'Moon', 'Mountain', 'Tree', 'Thunder', 'Earth'];

    /* array of 'predictions' for second part of message output */
    const predictionsArray = ['You are due good luck', 'Troublesome times are coming', 
        'A close friend is going to betray you', 'A new door is going to open for you', 
        'Lately, your sleep has been restless', 'In the near future you are going to have a choice to make'];

    /* array of 'advice' for final part of message output (preceeded by 'You should ') */
    const adviceArray = ['trust no one', 'keep your friends close', 'be generous', 'eat as much as possible',
        'get more sleep', 'learn a new skill'];

    /* function to select random element in provided array */
    const randomise = (array) => {
        let i = Math.floor(Math.random() * array.length);
        return array[i];
    }

    /* function to construct 3 part message using randomise() function */
    const generateMessage = () => {
        let part1 = `Your sign is ${randomise(signsArray)}`;
        let part2 = `${randomise(predictionsArray)}`;
        let part3 = `You should ${randomise(adviceArray)}.`;
        document.getElementById('div1').innerHTML = part1;
        document.getElementById('div2').innerText = part2;
        document.getElementById('div3').innerText = part3;
        document.getElementById('div1').removeAttribute('class');
        document.getElementById('div2').removeAttribute('class');
        document.getElementById('div3').removeAttribute('class');
        document.getElementById('div1').setAttribute('class', 'div1animate');
        document.getElementById('div2').setAttribute('class', 'div2animate');
        document.getElementById('div3').setAttribute('class', 'div3animate');
    };

    document.getElementById('generateButton').addEventListener('click', function(){
        generateMessage();
    });
};
```

```css
html {
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }
  *, *:before, *:after {
    box-sizing: inherit;
  }

body {
    background-color: #262833;
    font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    overflow: hidden;
    min-width: 95vw;
}

head, h1, h4 {
    color: #7E8CE0;
}

#generateButton {
    border-style: none;
    background-color: #3d415e;
    color: #7E8CE0;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    padding: 8px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    pointer-events: auto;
    position: relative;
}

#generateButton:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: #1f1f24;
    color: #f3f3f3;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

.textOutputDivs {
    color: #e0df81;
    font-size: 2em;
}

#wrapper {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    height: 100vh;
    min-width: 95vw;
}

header {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    width: fit-content;
}

#mainTitle {
    align-self: flex-start;
}

#mainSubTitle {
    align-self: flex-end;
}

main {
    align-self: center;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    height: 90vh;
    min-width: 95vw;
    padding-top: 50px;
}

#textOutputContainer {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
    align-items: center;
    margin-top: -50px;
    width: 90vw;
    max-width: 1100px;
    height: 100%;
    font-family: 'Anton', sans-serif;
}

#div1 {
    align-self: flex-start;
    width: fit-content;
    position: relative;
    color: #e0df81;
    font-size: 2em;
}

.div1animate {
    animation-name: slideAndFade;
    animation-duration: 3s;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    opacity: 0;
}

#div2 {
    align-self: center;
    width: fit-content;
    position: relative;
    color: #e0df81;
    font-size: 2em;
}

.div2animate {
    animation-name: slideAndFade;
    animation-duration: 3s;
    animation-delay: 0.25s;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    opacity: 0;
}

#div3 {
    align-self: flex-end;
    width: fit-content;
    position: relative;
    color: #e0df81;
    font-size: 2em;
}

.div3animate {
    animation-name: slideAndFade;
    animation-duration: 3s;
    animation-delay: 0.5s;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    opacity: 0;
}

/* keyframes animation to make text boxes slide in */
@keyframes slideAndFade {
    0%   { left: -100px; opacity: 0; }
    25%  { left: 0px; opacity: 1; }
    50%  { left: 0px; opacity: 1; }
    75%  { left: 0px; opacity: 1; }
    100% { left: 0px; opacity: 1; }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>Mixed Messages</title>
        <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <script src="scripts.js"></script>
        <!-- Google Fonts -->
        <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Ubuntu&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Anton&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="wrapper">
            <header>
                <h1 id="mainTitle">Mixed Messages</h1>
                <h4 id="mainSubTitle">by Rory Cotton</h4>
            </header>
            <main>
                <div id="generateButtonDiv">
                    <span id="generateButton">Generate Horoscope</span>
                </div>
                <div id="textOutputContainer">
                    <div class="textOutputDivs" id="div1"></div>
                    <div class="textOutputDivs" id="div2"></div>
                    <div class="textOutputDivs" id="div3"></div>
                </div>
            </main>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `overflow: hidden;` on body is not a great idea

Comment: why is that if you don't mind me asking?

Comment: Of course. Because it assumes you know the viewport of the browser visiting your site. Smaller browsers will now just cut off your content (as you can see in the code snippet preview itself) with no way of getting to the other content. In web you should assume as little as possible about the client platform. Hope this helps

Comment: You are right that you have to clear the animation in some way before you can get it to play again, but if you clear it and then immediately reset it the system won't realise. See [link]https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66524042/css-animation-wont-play-per-click/66526689#66526689

Answer (score 0):

Using this website as reference https://css-tricks.com/restart-css-animation/

```
function reset(){
    elm = document.getElementById('div1')
    newone = elm.cloneNode(true);
    elm.parentNode.replaceChild(newone, elm);
    elm = document.getElementById('div2')
    newone = elm.cloneNode(true);
    elm.parentNode.replaceChild(newone, elm);
    elm = document.getElementById('div3')
    newone = elm.cloneNode(true);
    elm.parentNode.replaceChild(newone, elm);
}
first = true
window.onload = function() {
/* array of 'signs' for first part of message output */
const signsArray = ['Sun', 'Moon', 'Mountain', 'Tree', 'Thunder', 'Earth'];

/* array of 'predictions' for second part of message output */
const predictionsArray = ['You are due good luck', 'Troublesome times are coming', 
    'A close friend is going to betray you', 'A new door is going to open for you', 
    'Lately, your sleep has been restless', 'In the near future you are going to have a choice to make'];

/* array of 'advice' for final part of message output (preceeded by 'You should ') */
const adviceArray = ['trust no one', 'keep your friends close', 'be generous', 'eat as much as possible',
    'get more sleep', 'learn a new skill'];

/* function to select random element in provided array */
const randomise = (array) => {
    let i = Math.floor(Math.random() * array.length);
    return array[i];
}

/* function to construct 3 part message using randomise() function */
const generateMessage = () => {
    let part1 = `Your sign is ${randomise(signsArray)}`;
    let part2 = `${randomise(predictionsArray)}`;
    let part3 = `You should ${randomise(adviceArray)}.`;
    document.getElementById('div1').innerHTML = part1;
    document.getElementById('div2').innerText = part2;
    document.getElementById('div3').innerText = part3;
    document.getElementById('div1').removeAttribute('class');
    document.getElementById('div2').removeAttribute('class');
    document.getElementById('div3').removeAttribute('class');
    document.getElementById('div1').setAttribute('class', 'div1animate');
    document.getElementById('div2').setAttribute('class', 'div2animate');
    document.getElementById('div3').setAttribute('class', 'div3animate');
};

document.getElementById('generateButton').addEventListener('click', function() 
{
    if(first){  
        generateMessage();
        first = false
    }
    else{
        reset()
    }
    
});
};
```